# Com Interop problem Silverlight 4 and MS Access 2010

Tags: silverlight, com, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to launch an existing MS Access database (Access 2010) from a Silverlight 4 OOB with elevated authorisation set. I keep getting an error. I can create a new Access application using the CreateObject keyword, but when I try to launch an existing one I get an error: "No object was found registered for specified ProgID."

Any help is appreciated. Here is the code I use:

```
string sMSAccess = "C:\\Users\\storltx\\Documents\\SL4Demo.accdb";
dynamic MSAccess = ComAutomationFactory.GetObject(sMSAccess);
MSAccess.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your code like this:-

```
string sMSAccess = "C:\\Users\\storltx\\Documents\\SL4Demo.accdb";
dynamic app = ComAutomationFactory.CreateObject("Access.Application");
app .Visible = true;
app.OpenCurrentDatabase(sMSAccess);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should pass "Access.Application" string to GetObject call. like this:

```
dynamic MSAccess = ComAutomationFactory.GetObject("Access.Application");
```

Comment: GetObject only works using the ProgID for previously activated objects.   Silverlight appears to be limited to only ProgIDs (which is why the approach in the question fails).  However this answer also won't work because it won't launch MSAccess and it doesn't indicate which database to load either.